# Catching DLL dependencies in Win32 application

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, dependencies, dependency-walker

How can I catch a missing DLL in a dependent DLL?

For example:
Application is loading a DLL A.

DLL A is loading DLL B.

So if DLL B is not available, application just shows me: DLL A not found.

Any hints where I could find a solution?

At the moment I use dependency-walker to solve this issue, but I need something inside the application, so that the customers must not launch the external tool whenever a DLL is missing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely clear what your use case is here, but can't your application call [LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to check if the DLLs are available before launching the "external tool", and if it fails report that the DLL(s) are missing?

Comment: This is how I would do it too.  Same as Jay's answer basically, but the call to LoadLibrary() is the key.  [See here, you'll get a NULL from LoadLibrary if A fails to load B.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could explicitly load the DLL. You'll get an error/exception if you have a missing dependency.

Perhaps you can statically compile the code in the DLL so the problem is eliminated?

If you're fighting with "[DLL Hell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_hell)" you might also be able to place the DLL's in the file system so windows will load the DLL's you want.

Comment: `you might also be able to place the DLL's in the file system` -- excuse me, where _else_ do you keep them?

Answer (score 0):

You can  parse [IAT](http://sandsprite.com/CodeStuff/Understanding_imports.html) and implement an [algorithm similar with the one used by LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to check if dll wil be found. A start in implementing this is [ImageNtHeader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680212%28VS.85%29.aspx)